# Returning second value in VBA vlookup

Tags: vba, vlookup

I am sure this is easy but cannot find a way to do this. I am trying to count the range in column A if <2 then can just the a regular vlookup to return the one answer but if greater than 2 I want the vlookup to return first answer in column 9 then second in column 10 etc can anyone help? hope this makes sense thanks.

```
    If (Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf _       
 (data.Range("A:A"), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(r, 2).Value)) < 2 _
        Then
        toh = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup _
        (ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(r, 2).Value, data.Range("A:N"), 14, False)
        Cells(r, 9) = toh
```

Answer (score 0):

Below Function May give you idea that how vloopkup works 
Function f_Apply_VlookupCalculation_Formulas(arrLookupWs, arrlookupRange, lookupColNo)
        'arrlookupRange = "$A$2:$E$2413"
        'arrLookupWs = Array("DD", "MM")
        'lookupColNo = 5
        intRowCount = Int(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Count)
        On Error Resume Next
        For x = 2 To intRowCount
            ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 4).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 1).Value, Sheets(arrLookupWs(0)).Range(arrlookupRange(0)), lookupColNo - 1, 0)
            ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 5).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 1).Value, Sheets(arrLookupWs(0)).Range(arrlookupRange(0)), lookupColNo, 0)
            ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 6).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 1).Value, Sheets(arrLookupWs(1)).Range(arrlookupRange(1)), lookupColNo - 1, 0)
            ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 7).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveSheet.Cells(x, 1).Value, Sheets(arrLookupWs(1)).Range(arrlookupRange(1)), lookupColNo, 0)
        Next
        On Error GoTo 0
        Erase arrLookupWs
        Erase arrlookupRange
        End Function

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with **array** formula

this will give the 1st, the normal vlookup

`=INDEX(I$1:I$13,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$13=$A$15,ROW($A$1:$A$13)),1),1)`

this will give the 2nd

`=INDEX(J$1:J$13,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$13=$A$15,ROW($A$1:$A$13)),**2**),1)`

this the 3rd, the  starred number incrementing each time, remove the stars

`=INDEX(K$1:K$13,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$13=$A$15,ROW($A$1:$A$13)),**3**),1)`

Wasn't sure if you were using VBA for a worksheet function or not or within a bigger function.

or something like this, where look for is the cell where the data you're doing countif on is, check values is column a, input range is the return you want, your columns 8 to ..... and column is the return, so to get the 2nd value, same data as the formula  id use

`VLOOKUP_NEW (range("a15"),range("a1:a13"),range("i1:k13"),2)`

```
Public Function VLOOKUP_NEW(rngLookFor As Excel.Range, _
                        rngCheckValues As Excel.Range, _
                        rngInputRange As Excel.Range, _
                        colReturn As Integer) As Variant

Dim c As Excel.Range
Dim arrRows() As Long

On Error GoTo eHandle

For Each c In rngCheckValues.Cells
    If c.Value = rngLookFor.Value Then
        arrRows(UBound(arrRows)) = c.Row
        ReDim Preserve a(UBound(arrRows) + 1)
    End If
Next c

VLOOKUP_NEW = WorksheetFunction.Index(rngInputRange, arrRows(colReturn - 1), colReturn)

Exit Function

eHandle:
    If Err.Number = 9 Then
        ReDim arrRows(0)
        Resume
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: This is great thanks and works as a formula, I am trying to use it in VB as part of a bigger project is this possible or do i need to use the formula in the spreadsheet instead?

Answer (score 0):

you try this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim valToSearch As Variant
    Dim Data As Range
    Dim nFilt As Long, r As Long, iArea As Long, iCount As Long, iAreaRow As Long

    r = 3 '<-- just for testing purposes
    Set Data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Range("A1:N20") '<-- just for testing purposes


    valToSearch = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(r, 2).Value'<-- store the value to search
    With Data '<-- refer to 'Data' range 
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=valToSearch '<--| filter first column of Data range on 'valToSearch' 
        nFilt = Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells.Resize(, 1)) - 1 '<--  count filtered values, assuming there's a header row I subtract 1 not to count its always visible row
        If nFilt > 0 Then '<-- if at least 1 data row filtered
            With .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<-- refer to 'Data' range filtered values header excluded 
                For iArea = 1 To .Areas.Count '<-- loop through areas
                    For iAreaRow = 1 To .Areas(iArea).Rows.Count '<-- loop through area rows
                        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(r, 9 + iCount) = .Areas(iArea).Cells(iAreaRow, 14) '<-- paste single filtered value in "Sheet2" cell starting from column 14 and offsetting one column rightwards at every pasting
                        iCount = iCount + 1 '<-- update pasted cells counter
                        If iCount = nFilt Then Exit For '<-- exit if pasted as many cells as filtered
                    Next iAreaRow
                    If iCount = nFilt Then Exit For '<-- exit if pasted as many cells as filtered
                Next iArea
            End With
        End If
        .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False '<-- shows unfiltered (hidden) rows back
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @g4cox , did you try this?